# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@mywebdomain.com" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel

I downloaded [this](https://dl.20script.ir/script/ads/awesomemailer%5Bwww.20script.ir%5D.zip) file and it used to work for around 8 months in a shared hosting environment. The SMTP Server is another server and the shared host connects to my SMTP Server.

With no changes at my end I get this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@mywebdomain.com" using 2 possible authenticators
```

The `.env` file contains only `mysql` connection string. The authentication related to email is inserted to database and it's working fine.

The current PHP version is 7.4 but I tried from 5.6 to 7.4 and none of them worked.

Can you help me regarding this? I googled this and almost all of the answers were about `gmail smtp`, while my SMTP is not gmail, I have my own server.

Comment: _"The authentication related to email is ... working fine."_ That's pretty clearly not the case. The credentials in the database changed, or the credentials on the SMTP server changed, or the SMTP server configuration changed and is no longer allowing the style of authentication you're using.

Comment: @AlexHowansky the only problem is with my host I think, because database connection is correct (login is valid), and my SMTP config is fine too (because I test this via Thunderbird and sending is fine and it's delivered to my gmail).

Comment: Well, if telnet works and thunderbird as well, then you have to check the library if username or password are correctly inserted , you have to enable the smtp debbuger and increase verbosity

Comment: @PsyLogic can you hint more how to debug and the verbose mode?

Comment: If you are using swiftmailer package you have to add [this plugin](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html#logger-plugin)  if you are using php mailer  you have to change `SMTPDebug` to `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3`; to get messages form client, server, and connection

Comment: @PsyLogic thanks, I didn't find any `SMTPDebug` in all of files, but it seems it's using `swiftmailer` and I don't know how to add that plugin because I don't know PHP. But I have a question if you can help me: how can I see which PHP version is needed for this application? I didn't find any sites for its devs.